# multiple buttons that redirect to different location

Tags: html

I have four buttons in a form when i click each button it should direct me to  its data. I have tried to write the ONCLICK direct to the page but nothing is happening.
Do i need a script to activate that or what preferably Javascript

Comment: What do you have in the onclick attribute?

Comment: Do you mean the form action should depend on which button was clicked? For example, when you click button 1, it'll take you to processor1.php, but when you click button 2, it'll be processor2.php?

Comment: yes that's what i want but am not using php

Answer (score 3):

You can make each button change the `action` attribute of the form before it submits, like this:

```
<form id="myform" method="GET" action="data1.html">
<input type="submit" value="Go to Data 1"
       onclick="document.forms['myform'].action='data1.html'">
<input type="submit" value="Go to Data 2"
       onclick="document.forms['myform'].action='data2.html'">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need script to redirect from a button yes.

It can be inline, or in a form of a function.

Inline:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='somepage.html'">
```

As function:

```
<script>
    function Redirect(e, url) {
        window.event.returnValue = false; //prevent event in IE 
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent event in FF 
        window.location.href = url;
    }
</script>
<form>
    <input type="submit" onclick="Redirect(event, 'somepage.html');">
</form>
```

Comment: oh the toher thing that happens is that when i click a button it gives the page cannot be displayed window .I have used both

Comment: Your input type submit needs to be specified in a form to work. The action on the form tells the page where to post to. If you dont specify an action, it will post to itself. You can also cancel the post event. Slightly different in IE and FF.

I made changes accordingly in above post.

Comment: it says the object doesnt support this property9(e.preventDefault().But i used another method.the function onSubmit form.the if the document.pressed =the name of the button it will direct me to the page expected.The only problem is when click a BACK button to return to the  main page,the next button on the main page doesnt go to the directed page.What might be the cause?